# Magento 1.9 How can i add the category name and category id in the canonical url

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, canonical

In ***magento 1.9*** I am trying to get the ***canonical*** URL for the category
In the view source, I am getting as

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://domain/categoy" />
```

I wanted to add the category id also in it can I do that?

can anyone help me how I can add the category Id to the canonical

currently, I am getting as

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://domainname/caregotyname" />
```

i also wanted to add the categoty id i don't the correct syntax but something like this is possible

```
<link rel="canonical" id='categoty_id' />
```

I am not sure but something like this

Answer (score 0):

With reference to this [link](http://ka.lpe.sh/2015/03/23/magento-change-canonical-url-for-particular-category-only/).

Please follow the steps.

– Go to the category page you want to change canonical URL in Magento Admin

– Click the tab “Custom Design”

– In the Custom Layout Update textbox, paste this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="removeItem" block="head">
        <item>link_rel</item>
        <name>http://loca.lho.st/old-canonical-url</name>
    </action>
    <action method="addLinkRel" translate="title">
        <rel>canonical</rel>
        <href>http://loca.lho.st/new-canonical-url</href>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Change the URL with your URL and it will be working.

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: thanks i reffered it but i want something like this
<link rel="canonical" href="https://domainname/caregotyname" />
<link rel="canonical" id='categoty_id' /> i am not sure but something like this